# How to compare a static data frame with a streaming one in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to compare two DataFrames. One of them is static and other is streaming.
Sample static DataFrame looks like the following:

```
 id, value
2786,  5
7252,  3
2525,  4
8038,  1
```

Sample streaming DataFrame looks like the following:

```
 id, value
2786,  9
7252,  8
2525,  7
```

The result DataFrame should look like this:

```
id, value
8038, 1
```

Value is not important at all. I just need to find that for this mini-batch I don't have a value with id 8038 specified. I tried to use joins and subtract() function for this, but the problem is that stream - static joins don't support the kinds of joins that I need, and subtract don't work when static DataFrame on the left. For example these expressions will return an error:

```py
staticDF.subtract(streamingDF)
staticDF.join(streamingDF, staticDF.id = streamingDF.id, "left_anti")
```

Is there any way to get the id that there is in staticDF, but not in streamingDF in Spark Structured Streaming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreachBatch sink and then use left anti join for static dataframe and micro batch.

```
streamingDf.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  println("------------------------")
  println("Batch "+batchId+ " data")
  println("Total Records " + batchDF.count())
  println("------------------------")
  staticDf.join(batchDF, staticDf("id") === batchDF("id"),"left_anti")
    .select(staticDf("*")).show()

//You can also write your output using any writer
//e.g. df.write.format("csv").save("src/test/resources")

}.start()
```

Inputs:

```
static df
+----+-----+
|  id|value|
+----+-----+
|2786|    5|
|7252|    3|
|2525|    4|
|8038|    1|
+----+-----+

streaming batch 0
2786,9
7252,8
2525,7

streaming batch 1
2786,9
7252,8
```

Output:

```
------------------------
Batch 0 data
Total Records 3
------------------------
+----+-----+
|  id|value|
+----+-----+
|8038|    1|
+----+-----+

------------------------
Batch 1 data
Total Records 2
------------------------
+----+-----+
|  id|value|
+----+-----+
|2525|    4|
|8038|    1|
+----+-----+
```